# Probability of acceptance for Rejection Sampling

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, rejection-sampling

I wondered if someone could confirm if this is correct. The probability of accepting a sample from the proposal distribution $q(z)$ is given by the ratio $\frac{\tilde {p}(z)}{kq(z)}$ where $\tilde {p}(z)$ is the unnormalised true posterior and $k$ the scaling factor. This itself is not the acceptance probability (although I thought it was). It seems the acceptance probability is $\frac{1}{k}$ which is rationalised as follows:

$\int \frac{\tilde {p}(z)}{kq(z)} q(z) dz = \frac{1}{k}$ which seems that we take an expectation over this acceptance probability to get an average over all terms? Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both quantities are acceptance probabilities, assuming of course that the dominating inequality$$\sup_{z\in\mathfrak X}\dfrac{\tilde {p}(z)}{kq(z)}\le 1$$holds.

First, the quantity$$\dfrac{\tilde {p}(z)}{kq(z)}$$is the *conditional* probability of acceptance given that $z$ is the outcome of a (marginal) simulation from $q(\cdot)$. Defining the indicator random variable
$$I=\mathbb I_{U\le {\tilde {p}(z)}/{kq(z)}}$$
when $U\sim \mathfrak U(0,1)$, $I\in\{0,1\}$ and is therefore a Bernoulli random variable. Conditionally on $Z=z$, when $Z\sim q(z)$, $I$ is a Bernoulli random variable$$\mathcal B(\tilde {p}(z)/{kq(z)})$$

Second, marginally, i.e., on its own, $I$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter
$$p=\mathbb P(I=1) = \int_\mathfrak Z \dfrac{\tilde {p}(z)}{kq(z)}
q(z)\text d z=\frac{1}{k}$$
(the last equality assuming *both* $\tilde p(\cdot)$ and $q(\cdot)$ are probability densities, i.e., are properly normalised). Therefore,
$1/k$ is the average and *marginal* probability of acceptance in the accept-reject algorithm.

Note that, while $Z$ is marginally distributed from $q(\cdot)$, conditional on $I$, we have
$$Z|I=1 \sim \tilde p(z) \quad\text{and}\quad Z|I=1 \sim \dfrac{kq(z)-\tilde p(z)}{k-1}$$

Comment: How can it be a marginal by definition? Wouldn't we require a joint distribution which we then integrate over to get the variable of interest? This seems more like an average as you also pointed out

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer to show this formally? I do not see how $I$ is marginally bernoulli $B(\frac{1}{K})$